# Consulta select por faixa etária

Tags: mysql, select

Fiz uma consulta `select` assim:

```
SELECT 
data,
sexo,
idade,
count(*) qtd
FROM marcacao
group by data, sexo, idade
```

E me retorna uma tabela semelhante à tabela abaixo:

```
DATA       | SEXO | IDADE | QTD
01/07/2017 |  F   |   30  |  3
01/07/2017 |  F   |   33  |  2
02/07/2017 |  F   |   45  |  4
03/07/2017 |  F   |   51  |  5
```

Quero fazer um `select` com base no `select` anterior, sendo que preciso filtrar por datas e por faixa etária, seria algo +- assim:

```
SELECT (Select_anterior)
where data >= dataini and data <= dataini
```

E o resultado deve sair por faixa etária, ex:

```
FAIXA ETARIA   | SEXO | QTD
0  - 10        |  F   |  30
11 - 20        |  F   |  22
21 - 30        |  F   |  13
31 - 40        |  F   |  28
```

Não sei se é possível fazer algo assim. Espero que tenham entendido minha dúvida, mas posso alterar a pergunta caso seja necessário.

Comment: Precisa agrupar os resultados um `case when` ou a função `if()` podem ajudar.

Comment: pode mostrar um exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o `IF`, abaixo um exemplo:

```
SELECT IF(idade <= 10, '0 - 10', IF(idade <= 20, '11 - 20', IF(idade <= 30, '21 - 30', IF(idade <= 40, '31 - 40', 0)))) faixa_etaria, sexo, count(*) qtd,
FROM marcacao
GROUP BY faixa_etaria
```

Nos comentários dessa resposta você pede para que o `SELECT` liste todas as faixas etárias, mesmo que não tenha ninguém. Para fazer isso tem duas alternativas.

A primeira necessita de uma tabela base, segue um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `faixa_etaria`(
    `idade_limite` INT,
    `faixa_etaria` CHAR(10) DEFAULT ''
);

INSERT INTO `faixa_etaria` (`idade_limite`, `faixa_etaria`) VALUES
(10, '1 - 10'),
(20, '11 - 20'),
(30, '21 - 30'),
(40, '31 - 40');
```

E o `SELECT` ser sobre essa tabela fazendo um `INNER JOIN` com sua tabela `marcacao`, segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT a.faixa_etaria, b.sexo, COUNT(a.idade) qtd,
FROM faixa_etaria a
LEFT JOIN marcacao b ON b.idade <= a.idade_limite
GROUP BY a.faixa_etaria
```

A segunda maneira de fazer isso é colocando os dados direto no seu `SELECT` desta forma:

```
SELECT a.faixa_etaria FROM (
    SELECT 10 idade_limite, '0 - 10' faixa_etaria
    UNION
    SELECT 20 idade_limite, '11 - 20' faixa_etaria
    UNION
    SELECT 30 idade_limite, '21 - 30' faixa_etaria
    UNION
    SELECT 40 idade_limite, '31 - 40' faixa_etaria
) a
LEFT JOIN marcacao b ON b.idade <= a.idade_limite
GROUP BY a.faixa_etaria;
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, preciso só de mais uma coisa: como fazer pra que, quando não exista informação naquela faixa etária, o sistema mostrar o número zero?

Comment: No ultimo `IF`, você coloca o `0`, editei minha resposta para exemplificar.

Comment: não funcionou, deixa eu explicar melhor: caso não exista nenhum item na faixa '11 - 20' ela não é mostrada no resultado. Quero que ela seja mostrada, mas com resultado igual a 0

Comment: Agora entendi o que você pretende, alterei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos supor que você esteja passando os parametros dataini, como:

```
$dataini = $_GET['dataini'];
```

Então as cláusulas WHERE devem ser:

```
SELECT 
    data,
    sexo,
    idade,
    count(*) qtd
    FROM marcacao
    WHERE
    (data >= '$dataini') and 
    (data <= '$dataini')
    group by data, sexo, idade
```

Comment: E como faço o agrupamento pelas faixas etárias?

Comment: Como você está passando os parâmetros?

Comment: Vou editar com passagem de parametro.

Comment: Oi, consegui fazer com o exemplo da outra resposta. Obrigado mesmo assim

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você possa fazer este filtro e agrupamento utilizando um "With" no SqlServer:

```
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, NumberOfOrders)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(*)  
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader  
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL  
    GROUP BY SalesPersonID  
)  
SELECT AVG(NumberOfOrders) AS "Average Sales Per Person"  
FROM Sales_CTE;  
GO
```

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
WITH TempTable (data, sexo, idade, qtd)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT 
        data,
        sexo,
        idade,
        count(*) qtd
    FROM marcacao
    GROUP BY data, sexo, idad
)  
SELECT [FormataçãoDoSeuResultado]   
FROM TempTable;  
GO
```

Comment: Não funciona com MySql

Answer (score -1):

Tente desta forma, você obterá uma lista com: `id`, `nome`, `idade`, `faixa inicial` e `faixa final`. Faça uma `view` com este `select`, depois é só agrupar por faixa.

```
SELECT
  can_id,
  can_nome,
  can_data_nacimento,
  (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(can_data_nacimento)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5) < RIGHT(can_data_nacimento,5)) AS idade,
  faixa_inicial,
  faixa_final   
FROM
  candidato,
  faixa_etaria --> tabela de faixa
WHERE can_data_nacimento is not null   
  AND (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(can_data_nacimento)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5) < RIGHT(can_data_nacimento,5))
  BETWEEN faixa_inicial AND faixa_final
```